# с# запрос на выборку из mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

Есть запрос к БД:

```
var sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = 'Иван Иванов'");
```

но он не работает, причем если условие изменить с текстового на цифры или с `name = 'Иван Иванов'` на `id = 1` - то все работает нормально.

Что не так с текстовым условием?

Comment: попробуйте `WHERE name LIKE 'Иван Иванов'`

Comment: "LIKE" тоже ничего не меняет. для эксперимента уже пробовал LIKE '%Иван Иванов%' и так же не работает.

Comment: И русские буквы из БД при этом выбираются нормально ? Может проблема с кодировкой. И пробовали ли вы выполнить тот же запрос из консоли MySQL может Иван Иванов в БД как то не так написан, пробел какой лишний или еще что нибудь. И кстати, что значит "не работает" ничего не возвращает или ошибку выдает

Comment: Кодировочки смотрите. По'ля таблицы, клиентского соединения с базой...

Comment: "не работает" - возвращает пустой результат. из консоли запрос работает и выводит результат. буду сейчас с кодировкой разбираться.

Comment: Скорее всего проблема с кодировкой. Попробуйте вытащить name, где будут английские буквы. Если все ок вытаскивает - кодировка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое это использовать параметры, дополнительный бонус - избежание опасностей SQLInjections.

```
MySQLCommand cmd = new MySQLCommand("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = @name", cnn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", MySQLDBType.VarChar).Value = "Иван Иванов";
MySQLDaraReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

////

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте приставку `N`

```
var sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = N'Иван Иванов'");
```